# Keeping background (zero values) transparent while converting array to shapefile with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geopandas, rasterio

I have predicted the binary mask and converted it to a shapefile after that I saved this vector file. But when I opened that file in QGIS it showed only borders, It doesn't make it with transparent background (which is zero values in the binary mask).

How can I make the background transparent? Here is the code that I have used and an image:

```py
def convert_array_to_vector(binary_mask: np.array, img_path: str) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """Convert masked array to vector file(.shp).

    Args:
        binary_mask: Output predicted binary mask.
        img_path: Path of the raster file used for the prediction.

    Returns:
        shp: GeoPandas DataFrame.

    """
    with rasterio.open(img_path, mode='r') as src:
        mask_meta = src.meta.copy()
        mask_meta.update(
            {
                'dtype': 'uint8',
                'count': 1,
                'nodata': 0.0
            }
        )

        with MemoryFile() as memfile:
            with memfile.open(**mask_meta) as mem:
                mem.write_band(1, binary_mask)
                geoms = dataset_features(
                    mem,
                    geographic=False,
                    as_mask=True,
                    with_nodata=True
                )
                shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
                    geoms,
                    crs=str(mem.crs).lower(),
                    columns=['geometry', 'val']
                )
    return shp

def save_vector_file(shp: gpd.GeoDataFrame, dest_path: str) -> None:
    """Write vector file to the disk.

    Args:
        dest_path: Destionation path to save the vector file.
        shp: vector dataframe.

    """
    shp.to_file(dest_path)
```

The converted image:

[image]

The image that I want to have:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`rasterio.features.shapes`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes) instead of [`dataset_features`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.dataset_features) you don't need to create a dataset, you can just use your numpy array and a `transform`.

In the example below I've used a donut shaped mask (numpy uint8 array) where 1's are black and 0's are aqua:

[image]

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.features import shapes
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

def convert_array_to_vector(binary_mask: np.array, img_path: str) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """Convert masked array to vector file(.shp).

    Args:
        binary_mask: Output predicted binary mask.
        img_path: Path of the raster file used for the prediction.

    Returns:
        shp: GeoPandas DataFrame.

    """
    with rio.open(img_path, mode='r') as src:

        # create a dict of features generator
        features = (
            {'properties': {'value': value}, 'geometry': shape}
            for (shape, value) in shapes(
                mask, mask=mask.astype("bool"), transform=src.transform
            )
        )

        shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
            features,
            crs=src.crs,  # no need to convert to string
            columns=['geometry', 'value']
        )

    return shp
```

Output shapefile:

[image]